# PHP 5.5.6 (exchangeing data between methods) calling private method and static variable from getValue method, works only after setting new value

Tags: php

Please, can someone explain to me - what is the reason of this error?.. why it works fine, after assigning new value to $variable

```
<?php

 class MyClass {

   var $variable = 'first_variable';
   static $qt = 1;

   public function getValue() {
     return $this->variable . ' - calling getValue: ' . MyClass::increment();
   }

   public function setValue($pass) {
     return $this->variable = $pass;
   }

   private function increment() {

     return $this->qt++;
   }

 }

 $ob = new MyClass();
 echo $ob->getValue();

 $ob->setValue('changed_variable');

 echo '<br>' . $ob->getValue();
 echo '<br>' . $ob->getValue();
 echo '<br>' . $ob->getValue();
```

gives error only for first value, and then works fine,

Error: **Notice: Undefined property: MyClass::$qt in C:\xampp\htdocs\somename\1.php on line 18**

```
first_variable - calling getValue:
changed_variable - calling getValue: 1
changed_variable - calling getValue: 2
changed_variable - calling getValue: 3
```

Comment: if I change style or scope of variable form static $qt = 1 to var $qt =1 or ptivate $qt=1 ...just works ... but if I change scope of $qt to private static, not... How to pass referece ? why they not operating each other?

Comment: SOLVED:<br>

in this case problem was that I was trying accessing static property as non static.<br>

the resolution is  private function increment() {

     return MyClass::qt++;
   }

Answer (score 0):

in this case problem was that I was trying accessing static property as non static.
the resolution is

```
private function increment()
 { 
return MyClass::qt++; 
}
```